# Can't set static folder express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, plesk

I'm trying to set a static folder for my index.html file and other folders like css, img and js scripts.
but i don't manage to set a static folder successfully.
this is my app.js code:

```
     const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'httpdocs')))
// app.get('/', (req, res) => {
//     res.sendFile('index.html')

// });

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.listen(PORT, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);

})
```

my file tree is like this:

```
---node/
     ------httpdocs (i want this to be static folder
           ---css/
           ---js/
           ---img/
           --index.html (this file should be loaded when loading the root link)
   ---app.js (nodejs script)
```

p.s: im using plesk on windows so if this makes any difference tell me.

Answer (score 1):

I can see the only error is in below line.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'httpdocs'))
```

Try to print below tow different method using console :

```
console.log(__dirname+ 'httpdocs');
console.log(path.join(__dirname, 'httpdocs'));
```

Output:

```
...\nodehttpdocs
...\node\httpdocs
```

I hope you get the solution.

If you are trying to manually merge path then you have to add path separator '\' externally

```
Ex: app.use(express.static(__dirname + '\httpdocs'));
```

Or else use below method

```
Ex: app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'httpdocs')));
```

I suggest using path.join method. Because it will add path separator based on the operating system. Or else you have to manage manually.

Comment: sorry, it didn't work for me.you can check my website [generationz.dev] you'll see the homepage displayed without css nor pictures. but if you go to generationz.dev/httpdocs/index.html you'll see the full page with css and images

Comment: @MendiSterenfeld
Your all link should start with httpdocs path.
Your code:
<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
It should be :
<link href="httpdocs/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

I suggest you use '/' before all URL for using resource irrelative to the current path.
So it would look like :
<link href="/httpdocs/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: this is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. Isn't there another way?

Comment: @MendiSterenfeld
Please upload your updated code of app.js in question

Comment: Tried to run the same code with the same directory structure and I can access static folder data without passing static folder name in URL. 
http://localhost:5000/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
Please make sure your server is restarted or you are making the change at the correct place.

Comment: so you say it could be a problem with the server?